# How to test in SPSS: categorical with continuous predictor and categorical response?

Tags: regression, spss, survival, proportional-hazards

Edited:

I'm a statistics newbie, so please be gentle

I'm trying to figure out what test to use to analyze a categorical concurrent with continuous predictor for a categorical response.

For example:

How is hypertension with incrementally increasing age associated with overall death?

I'm trying to determine if hypertension is associated with overall death to varying degrees depending on the patient's age 
i.e. As patients get older, they are more likely to die if they have hypertension than if they did not.
I have both time to death (continuous) and event of death (categorical) data.

All and any advice will be very much appreciated (I'm using SPSS v22.0)! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your predictor is categorical and you response variable is continues, you need to dummy code your predictor variable.

your question is not very clear, so it is better to further clarify it.